# R: How to create a loop for, for a range of data in a function?

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have this parameter:

```
L_inf <- seq(17,20,by=0.1)
```

and this function:

```
fun <- function(x){
  L_inf*(1-exp(-B*(x-0)))}
```

I would to apply this function for a range of value of `L_inf`.
I tried with loop `for`, like this:

```
A <- matrix() # maybe 10 col and 31 row or vice versa
for (i in L_inf){
A[i] <- fun(1:10)
}
```

Bur R respond: `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`. 
My expected output is a matrix (or data frame, or list maybe) with 10 result (`fun(1:10)`) for each value of the vector `L_inf` (lenght=31).
How can to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to put a vector of 10 elements into one of the matrix cell. You want to assign it to the matrix row instead (you can access the ith row with `A[i,]`).

But using a for loop in this case is inefficient and it is quite straightforward to use one of the "apply" function. `Apply` functions typically return a list (which is the most versatile container since there is basically no constraint).

Here `sapply` is an apply function which tries to **S**implify its result to a convenient data structure. In this case, since all results have the same length (10), `sapply` will simplify the result to a matrix.

Note that I modified your function to make it explicitly depend on L_inf. Otherwise it will not do what you think it should do (see keyword "closures" if you want more info).

```
L_inf_range <- seq(17,20,by=0.1)
B <- 1

fun <- function(x, L_inf) {
    L_inf*(1-exp(-B*(x-0)))
}

sapply(L_inf_range, function(L) fun(1:10, L_inf=L))
```

Comment: ,I want to test the stationary of time series data , build ARIMA models, predicting, every 30 rows of the time series, how can I go about it? I have multiple time series data in a long format under the same variable and a single time series has 30 years of data, I want to replicate the 30 years time series in to 4, i.e 4*30= 120 observations. Thank you very much for your assistance!