# How to apply (or sapply) a function for double range of data?

Tags: r, sapply

I have this function

```
fun_2 <- function(x,L_inf,y){
  L_inf-((L_inf-y)/
            (exp(-B*(x-c(1:12))/12)))
}
B <- 0.5
```

The problem is similar this previous post [R: How to create a loop for, for a range of data in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720954/r-how-to-create-a-loop-for-for-a-range-of-data-in-a-function)
In this case i would to apply the `fun_2` for this two range of data:

```
L_inf_range <- seq(17,20,by=0.1) #31 values
y_range <- seq(4,22,by=0.1)  # 19 values
```

I tried with:

```
sapply(L_inf_range, function(L) fun_2(12, L_inf=L,y_range))
```

but is not the expected output. My expected output is a new matrix genereted by `sapply`(or other kind of function) where the `fun_2` is apply for all the value in `L_inf_range` and each time for all value of `y_range`.

Substantially it will be a matrix where `fun_2` is apply for each values of `L_inf_range`(31 values) minus  `y_range` (`L_inf-y` in `fun_2`) each time.

Comment: You can create a data.frame with all combinations and go through each with `apply`. You'll have to somehow include `x` into this since you don't specify what are the values. `expand.grid(x = ?, L_inf_range, y_range, B = 0.5)`

Comment: `outer` might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could also run sapply twice changing the order of your arguments to make it, a little easier.

```
    fun_2_mod <- function(y, L_inf, x = X){ fun_2(x, L_inf, y)}

    sapply(y_range, function(Y){sapply(L_inf_range, fun_2_mod, y = Y)})
```

You can bind the resulting list of lists together into a data frame.